# Is there a way to pass a dynamic list into a ListView component?

Tags: lightning, aura, list, component

When using a ListView lightning component, is there a way to pass a dynamic list in as opposed to an existing List View? Or would a list view have to be made completely from scratch in order for that to be possible?